# make one div have the same width as another one

Tags: html, css, styled-components

I have two divs, and one of has data coming from api, and its width changes depending on how much text/numbers are returned from api.

Im trying to make another div align itself according to what the first div's width is.

[This is an explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYDyn.png)

This is the html structure

```
<div>
<h5 class="test">First Text</h5>
</div>

<div>
    <h5 class="test">First Text</h5>
 </div>

<div>
    <h5 class="test">${API_DATA}</h5>
 </div>
```

Each div has a styling of:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
```

with two columns as this is [the structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1Yuv.png)

how can i make it have the same width as the last div no matter how long the data is?

Comment: Flexbox is the answer. This should help you understand: https://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/

Answer (score 0):

You can use for this case the CSS property: `display: inline-block`. Assign it to the h5 Element for example.

```css
.test {
  display: inline-block;  
  background: gray;
  margin: 10px;
  padding:10px;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="w">
  <div class="b">
    <h5 class="test">First Text</h5>
  </div>

  <div class="b">
      <h5 class="test">First Text</h5>
   </div>

  <div class="b">
      <h5 class="test">${API_DATA} 123</h5>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

with javascript :

```
let divs = document.getElementsByClassName("test")

for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].style.width = 50
}
```

Comment: OP has has asked for CSS anser not in JabaScript. It's best to answer with the what user has asked for.